# Powershell: Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Name'. Specified method is not supported

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm totally new to **powershell.** I'm to trying to extract system information & Installed apps information using powershell. So, I used join statement to execute 3 commands simultaneously:

```
write-output -join($(Get-ComputerInfo), "," , $(Get-AppxPackage –AllUsers ) , "," , 
$(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product)) | Out-File  .\a.txt
```

It's running absolutely fine without any errors when i **run directly in powershell**. But, I tried something like pasting same command in text file & saved with extension .ps1. Then i used command

```
./code.ps1
```

It started throwing error like

```
Get-AppxPackage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required 
by parameter 'Name'. Specified method is not supported.
```

I don't get it. When i run same command directly in powershell it's running fine with no errors.

Comment: The error message implies that you're running a _different_ command, namely one in which you attempt to pass _multiple_ arguments to `Get-AppXPackage`'s `-Name` parameter. Also note that the `-join` operator won't work in a command argument as written unless you enclose the entire operation in `(...)`, and that it's best not to invoke it as if it were a method; that is, use `-join ('foo', 'bar')`, not `-join('foo', 'bar')`.

Comment: Thank you for your time.....Seriously i starterd working on powershell  like back one hour..I never used it in past....I dont completly understood your content..But yes, I got some clarity ...I will modify my syntax & i will let you know ~~~Thanks :)

Comment: Understood; PowerShell can be confusing at first. It's important to show the actual command that triggered the error message, but here's an easy way to provoke it `Get-AppxPackage foo, bar` (same as: `Get-AppxPackage -Name foo, bar`)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense @mklement0 .....But, Thing i dont get is....If i execute same as it is command directly on power shell i'm getting my required outputs without errors.....it's throwing problems when i execute same command from ./code.ps1 file......Anyway i will modify my syntax as you said...I will let you know...Really really thank you for your time~~

Answer (score 1):

Use a semicolon to chain commands in PowerShell: in your case

```
write-output -join($(Get-ComputerInfo) ; $(Get-AppxPackage –AllUsers ) ;
$(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product)) | Out-File  .\a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking off [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), I think the source of the error is you are trying to convert the array returned by `Get-AppxPackage –AllUsers` into a String.